# Count unread mails From Exchange Server 2003 (outlook Web App) from C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, exchange-server-2003

Count unread mails From Exchange Server 2003 (outlook Web App) from C#

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you.

Considering you are running 2003 you probably need to look into WebDav. Exchange 2007/10 have a nice set of WebServices.

Check this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikas/archive/2009/03/03/howto-webdav-exchange-2003-poll-for-unread-emails-notify-admin-if-a-predefined-level-is-reached.aspx